# Fragment transaction doesn't always work as intended

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this problem in an app, where that method below doesn't always effectively hide the currently visible fragment (contentFragment) and shows the new one (fragment). Basically, sometimes, it does the complete opposite of what it's supposed to do, that is, the current fragment remaining visible, and the new one not showing at all. And what is worth, is that I can't always replicate when it happens.

I'm really at wits' end here. Anyone got any ideas?

```
public void addContentFragment(GenericFragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = slidingMenusActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.ContentLayout, fragment, fragment.getFragmentTag());
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getFragmentTag());

    Log.d(TAG, "addContentFragment hiding contentFragment=" + contentFragment);

    transaction.hide(contentFragment);
    transaction.commit();

    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    contentFragment = fragment;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **contentFragment** sometimes do not have the value you are expecting, try to retrieve the current fragment to ensure you are really hiding the fragment before your new transaction.

Modify your `addContentFragment(GenericFragment fragment)` as the follows:

```
public void addContentFragment(GenericFragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = slidingMenusActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ContentLayout);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.ContentLayout, fragment, fragment.getFragmentTag());
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getFragmentTag());

    Log.d(TAG, "addContentFragment hiding contentFragment=" + contentFragment);

    transaction.hide(currentFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion :)
It makes sense and works, but I can't tell if it really fixed the problem, since it rarely happens. Well, it should work, in theory. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't really pinpoint where in the code contentFragment is being set unexpectedly to another value, but using findFragmentById like you suggested, is much more trustworthy to avoid these kind of problems, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Yeah, you ensure the fragment you hide is the current shown fragment and also you avoid to maintain a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that, sorry xD